# How to use EBNF grammar for a small language?

Tags: c++, recursion

I am working on an assignment that parses a file with EBNF grammar, I am a little confuse on the recursive function work.

-first three functions:

```
Prog ::= PROGRAM IDENT; DeclBlock ProgBody
DeclBlock ::= VAR {DeclStmt;}
DeclStmt ::= Ident {, Ident} : (Integer | Real | String)
```

I Know that you're supposed to call Prog first then DeclBlock and then DeclStmt. So when you call DeclBlock, do you call it again only when you see the semicolon or when you see another IDENT? Same goes for DeclStmt, do you call it again only when you see a comma?

```
//Prog ::= PROGRAM IDENT; DeclBlock ProgBody
bool Prog(istream& in, int& line){
    bool status;
    LexItem t;
    
    t = Parser::GetNextToken(in, line);
    cout << t << endl;

    if(t != PROGRAM){
        ParseError(line, "Missing PROGRAM");
        return false;
    }

    LexItem i = Parser::GetNextToken(in,line);

    cout << i << endl;
    if(i != IDENT){
        ParseError(line, "Missing Program Name");
        return false;
    }

    LexItem semi = Parser::GetNextToken(in, line);
    cout << semi << endl;
    if(semi != SEMICOL){
        ParseError(line, "Missing SemiColon");
        return false;
    }

    status = DeclBlock(in, line);

    if(!status){
        ParseError(line, "Incorrect Declaration Section.");
        return false;
    }

    LexItem b = Parser::GetNextToken(in, line);

    cout << "here at b" << b << endl;

    if(b != BEGIN){
        ParseError(line, "Non-recognizable Program Block");
        ParseError(line, "Incorrect Program Section");
        return false;
    }

    status = ProgBody(in, line);

    if(!status){
        ParseError(line, "Incorrect Program Block");
        return false;
    }

    LexItem e = Parser::GetNextToken(in, line);

    cout << e << endl;

    if(e != END){
        ParseError(line, "Non-recognizable Program Block");
        ParseError(line, "Incorrect Program Section");
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
//DeclBlock ::= VAR {DeclStmt;}
bool DeclBlock(istream& in, int& line){
    bool status = false;
    
    LexItem v = Parser::GetNextToken(in, line);

    cout << v << endl;

    if(v != VAR){
        ParseError(line, "Non-recognizable Declaration Block.");
        return false;
    }

    status = DeclStmt(in, line);

    if(!status){
        ParseError(line, "Syntactic error in Declaration Block.");
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

//DeclStmt ::= Ident {, Ident} : (Integer | Real | String)
bool DeclStmt(istream& in, int& line){
    bool status = false;
    LexItem tok = Parser::GetNextToken(in, line);
    cout << "here too " <<  tok << endl;

    if (defVar.find(tok.GetLexeme()) != defVar.end()) {
        cout << "Var Exists!" << endl;
        ParseError(line, "Var cant be redeclared");
        return false;
    }
    else{
        defVar.insert({tok.GetLexeme(), true});
    }

    LexItem c = Parser::GetNextToken(in, line);

    cout << c << endl;

    if(c == COMMA){
        //cout << "before calling declStmt" << endl;
        status = DeclStmt(in, line);
        //cout << "after calling declStmt" << endl;
    }
    else if(c.GetToken() == IDENT){
        ParseError(line, "Unrecognized Input Pattern");
        cout << "( here " << c.GetLexeme() << ")" << endl;
        return false;
    }
    // else if(c == IDENT){
    //  ParseError(line, "Missing comma");
    //  return false;
    // }
    else{
        // Parser::PushBackToken(c);

        if(c != COLON){
            ParseError(line, "Missing Colon");
            return false;
        }

        LexItem t = Parser::GetNextToken(in, line);

        cout << "here t " << t.GetLexeme() << endl;

        if(t.GetLexeme() != "REAL" && t.GetLexeme() != "INTEGER" && t.GetLexeme() != "STRING"){
            ParseError(line, "Incorrect Declaration Type.");
            return false;
        }

        LexItem semi = Parser::GetNextToken(in,line);

        cout << semi << endl;

        if(semi != SEMICOL){
            ParseError(line, "Missing SemiColon");
            return false;
        }

        

        return true;
    }

    return status;
}
```

Comment: The way this grammar is written you only end up in `DeclBlock` once - when you get there from `Prog`. There is no other path that it can be reached

Comment: Then how do you get multiple DeclStmt? Arent you supposed to keep calling declBlock if there is a semicolon to get get another DeclStmt?

Comment: You don't call `DeclBlock` multiple times, you don't finish it until you run out of `DeclStmt;` (since they are a repetition inside `DeclBlock`)

Comment: So the only function being called again multiple times is DeclStmt?

Comment: In this grammar snippet, yes

Comment: Ok, It seem like I was doing the wrong thing then. thank you !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`DeclBlock` should only be called once in this language. `DeclStmt` can be called multiple times. A `DeclStmt` is defined to be one or more `Ident` followed by `:`, followed by a type, then ending in a `;`.

After you read the `;` at the end of a `DeclStmt`, you'd then read the next token to decide what to do next. If the next token is another `Ident` you know you're at the start of another `DeclStmt`, so you'd call that again. If it's anything else, you know you're at the start of `ProgBody`. (I'm assuming the last bit. Normally you'd look for the token that starts a `ProgBody`, but that's not shown.)

Comment: Yes the next function is ProgBody ::= BEDIN {Stmt;} END, so if the next token is anything else but a IDENT then I return all the way back to Prog and start ProgBody?

Comment: @ovl821 Knowing how `ProgBody` starts, I would look for either `Ident` or `BEGIN` to decide what to do next. Anything else should raise an error.

Comment: can you check my code above? still think im doing it wrong

Comment: @ovl821 In `DeclStmt`, I'm not sure about this part: `else if(c.GetToken() == IDENT){` If the token wasn't a comma, then you should be expecting a colon. I think you can look for `:` and raise an error if it's anything else.

Comment: I did that because if we're missing a comma and there is an IDENT then that is an error like ```a r, sum : REAL``` - (a, r ,sum being IDENT). this will only give me one DeclStmt. what happens if its this -
``` 
a, b ,c : STRING;
r, d , sum : REAL
```

Answer (score 0):

Your DeclBlock function should be something like

```
bool DeclBlock(istream& in, int& line) {
    if (Parser::GetNextToken(in, line) != VAR) {
        // missing VAR
        return false; }
    while (Parser::Lookahead(in, line) != BEGIN) {
        if (!DeclStmt(in, line)) {
            // error in the DeclStmt
            return false; }
        if (Parser::GetNextToken(in, line) != SEMICOL) {
            // error -- missing semicolon
            return false; }
    }
    return true;
}
```

The key thing is that you *MUST* have a parser lookahead function that gives you the next token WITHOUT consuming it.

Comment: I see what you're saying but by doing this way, its not calling it recursively right?

Comment: No it's not, but you don't have any recursive rules in the grammar fragment you show, so there's no need for recursive calls.

Comment: Got it! I think ill go with this way, thank you !